# Lenovo IdeaPad A1 Tablet - Micro USB or Mini USB?

Tags: usb, lenovo-laptop

What kind of USB port does the Lenovo IdeaPad A1 tablet have? The title description says "micro usb" but "mini usb" is mentioned in the info text below: http://www.amazon.ca/Lenovo-7-Inch-Ideapad-Tablet-Micro-USB/dp/B005UBT7LW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tablet/ideapad/a1/ says

> Micro-USB connector

I would go with lenovo's specs.

Comment: In the Lenovo shop they are saying it's a MINI USB: http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:category.details?current-catalog-id=12F0696583E04D86B9B79B0FEC01C087&current-category-id=125EC838A7312DD4A397B55779CFA876&tabname=Features

Comment: man that is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It says a mini USB... But the picture is a micro USB...
[Here](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tablet/ideapad/a1/A1_Datasheet_US.pdf) is the product sheet, [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Mini_and_Micro_connectors) is a link to the wikipedia about micro and mini usb

Answer (score 0):

From the photos, I'd say [Micro-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Physical_appearance).